# highcharts x axis date variable range

Tags: date, highcharts

I have difficulty to make date range in x-axis for highcharts.
It based on user input that can have various date range, can be a month, 14 days, 2 months, etc.

Is it possible to give minimum and maximum date, and let the highcharts arrange the scaling between min and max date?
And how will be the correct syntax?

appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set min/max values for xAxis, but dynamic version can be achived by using variables defiend by user.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.min
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.max

Comment: Sebastian after dates in a date range picker are updated and new variables stored should `redraw();` be used or another function to update the chart with the new min / max values?